# View live updates from MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, html, live

I want to create a page where people can insert some text, hit enter, and the text be stored in a MySQL database.  I can do this, but I want to be able to load a page, enter a password, and see a list of all the info in said database, then whenever something is added to the database, it's added to the list on the page, without me needing to refresh the page or setup some javascript code to refresh the page every five seconds.

Comment: Ajax will be of  great help in this case

Comment: you can do it using Iframe and use AJAX

Answer (score 0):

I believe Satya has it correct in suggesting that you use Ajax in order to refresh the data without refreshing the page. You can have it request updated information from a php script which queries your database for the data you wish to display, and then sets the elements on your page accordingly.

this is probably the best way for you to implement ajax calls using javascript
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Or you an simly do it with the help of `setInterval()` function. You can call an html code in a div using

```
$('#id').html("<htmlcode></htmlcode>");
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/995PJ/6/